# Pine tradingview get plot value with offset

Tags: pine-script

How to get the value of an ema with a offset applied (id want the offset) to be in the past aka -5 bars for example

```
plot(ema(close, 15), offset=-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to refer to past values of time series using the [] history-referencing operator

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")


ema = ta.ema(close, 15)
plot(ema15[5], color = color.red)
```

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#history-referencing-operator

Answer (score 0):

you can just try this

```
LIFE32 = ta.ema(close, 3)
    
    plotshape(LIFE32[2] < close, "LIFE UP", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color=color.green)
```